# gwt getOffsetWidth returns zero

Tags: gwt

I need to get the width of a widget after it has been rendered on the screen, because when I try to get its width after it is attached it returns zero.  What is the earliest time I can retrieve the valid offsetwidth of a widget?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

The offset width of the box only is known after the browser had built the content of the page. Use `scheduleDefferred()`, then you can get the value.

Example:

```
final TextBox yourInput = new TextBox();
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

  @Override
  public void execute() {
    int width = yourInput.getOffsetWidth();
    /* Do anything with width */
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Widget's onLoad() method. It is a no op method you can override, immeditely called after a widget becomes attached to the browser's document.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I've tried onLoad & onAttach.  The fact is that not even my parent has a width.  The parent is a DockPanelLayout, and that maybe that is why...

Comment: Normally onLoad() would do the trick but since DockLayoutPanel has this animate() method to place its children, you can't access their width, height right away. Internally it should call doLayout(), but since it is private, one thing you can do is to call [forceLayout()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html#forceLayout()) to lay its children immediately. Then you can access its children's height and width.

Answer (score 1):

Try a combination of onLoad() and scheduleFinally().

In the code below, the "onResize" and "scheduleFinally" callbacks will always have good results.  Between the two of them, you should catch all required events.

"onLoad" will often return 0 for the size, as described in the original problem.  You can just skip that part.

```
    @Override
    public void onResize() {
        recordSize("onResize");     
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoad() {
        super.onLoad();
        recordSize("onLoad");   
        Scheduler.get().scheduleFinally(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand()
        {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                recordSize("scheduleFinally");
            }});
    }
```

Comment: Actually scheduleEntry() is more reliable than scheduleFinally().